# Cleaning system from removed applications trash

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec, maintenance, ccleaner

## Details

**My OS:** Windows 7 Ultimate X64 with SP1

I'm using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) for daily, weekly PC cleanings.

Recently during uninstallation of Acronis True Image, uninstaller crashed and closed itself at the half of uninstallation process. I'm pretty sure that, it doesn't finished operation and the big part of application still exists between system files.

## Question

- Is there any **freeware** software that safely analyzes and cleans
  system from this kind of trash (trashes of applications which
  unfinished uninstalling, etc..)?
- As I mentioned above, i'm using CCleaner. But I really don't know, how "safe" this kind of applications are?! My Windows now works well. There are tons of applications & configuration installed. I'm not sure, if after each CCleaner's cleaning, my Windows will work properly or not (for ex, it will delete some important file or reg entry.. etc)
  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [Revo Uninstaller Free](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this sort of thing happens, your computer is left in an inconsistent state, as far as the (un)installed software is concerned.

To resolve this, what I normally do is reinstall the offending software, then uninstall it again (with a reboot in between for good measure).

Owing to the massive number of applications and their varied installers out there, no single application can manage this safely for you. Revo Uninstaller is pretty good for some things, but if the registry no longer contains a record of an installed program, you're out of luck.